# ajax call to controller when value selected from select box

Tags: php, ajax, select, controller

i want to make a ajax call to controller when a value 
is selected from select box.

this is my code:

```
<select class="form-control required"  name="law_name" id="law_name">
    @foreach($law_name as $lawname)
    <option value="{{$lawname->id}}">{{$lawname->law_name}}
    </option>
 @endforeach    
 </select>

<script>
    $("#law_name").on('change', function(){
                alert('123');
                $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: data,
                        url: "{{ URL::to('admin/SubLawController/index') }}",
                        success: function (response) {
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

my script is not running when i change value from select box

Comment: Where the ajax code?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: is that worked for you ??????????

Answer (score 0):

following is jquery code for making ajax call on change event of dropdown box,

```
$(function() {
     $("#law_name").change(function () {
           alert( $('option:selected', this).text() );
          $.ajax({url: "http://xyz"+ $( this ).text(), success: function(result)
         {
               $("#div1").html(result);
          }});      
    });
});
```

Code is in jquery , you have to use xmlhttprequest object for pain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Client Details *</label>
    <input type="text" name="ClientId" id="ClientId" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
</body>
    
    <script>
    $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + 'getfile/ClientDetails',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',           
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);            
                var testdata = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];
                console.log(testdata);
                let data = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    //console.log(result[i]);
                    data.push.apply(data,result[i]);
                }
                console.log(data);
                     
    
    $("#ClientId").select2({
      data: data,
      minimumResultsForSearch: 20
    })
    
    }
    }); 
    
    </script>
    
  <?php  
     function ClientDetails() {
       
        $getAllClients = getdetails($id);
        $getAllClients = $getAllClients['Accountdetails'];
             
        $details = [];        
        foreach($getAllClients as $val){
            $id = $val['id'];
            $name = $val['client_name'];
            $details[] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'text' => $name
            );
        }
            
        print_r(json_encode(array($details)));
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.